# Why does a sigaction handler not handle every signal even if the SA_NODEFER flag is set?

Tags: c, signals

I have a parent process that spawns ten child processes and uses a SIGCHILD handler to notify when a child process has died. The child processes will notify when they have started and will then exit immediately.
I use the SA_NODEFER flag to prevent SIGCHLD signals to get discarded when too many are coming in. The children are all being correctly terminated and reaped, but in this script and also when terminating two at the same time via the console signals send at the same time always appear as one.

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

void CHLDHandler(int sig)
{
  char child[] = "Child finished!\n";
  write(1, &child, sizeof(child));
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {

  struct sigaction sa;
  sa.sa_handler = CHLDHandler;
  sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
  sa.sa_flags = SA_NODEFER;

  sigaction(SIGCHLD,&sa,NULL);

  for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    int pid = fork();

    if (pid == 0)
    {
      int pid = getpid();
      printf("I'm a child with pid %d!\n", pid);
      return 0;
    }
  }
  while(1)
  {
    wait(NULL);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is apropos, if it isn't an exact duplicate:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8398298/handling-multiple-sigchld

Comment: I see. My task states that it should be a signal handler and apparently the man page for signalfd says that it is an alternative to signal handlers. So while the other way would work it seems to also be doable with a signal handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basic UNIX signals do not queue — only one can be pending (for a given thread) at a time.

If two child processes terminate at effectively the same time and thus deliver their SIGCHLD at the "same" time, your process will have only one signal pending.

`wait`ing *in a loop* after receipt of a SIGCHLD is a long-established technique to compensate for the fact that a SIGCHLD may be "lost".  Move the "Child finished!\n" announcement to the loop that calls `wait`, and you'll have an accurate count.

### UPDATE

If you *must* reap within your handler, you may call `wait` within the handler, since it is [async-signal-safe](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_04_03):

```
static void CHLDHandler(int sig)
{
  static char child[] = "Child finished!\n";
  int save_errno = errno;

  while (waitpid((pid_t)-1, NULL, WNOHANG) > 0) {
    write(STDERR_FILENO, &child, sizeof(child) - 1);  // don't write the terminating NULL
  }

  errno = save_errno;
}
```

In this case I would *not* set SA_NODEFER, since another SIGCHLD might interrupt (EINTR) the `waitpid` or the `write` calls.

Comment: Thanks, for the answer. I tried that method and it worked perfectly!
My task explicitly states to solve this with a handler though. Would it be correct to say terminating child processes can not be correctly announced, because my process manager only sends so many signals from them?

Comment: @NiklasN., how about the sig handler in my update to this answer?

Comment: wouldn't that one call the handler for the first one and then stay in it? I'm looking for a way to call the handler every time a signal comes in, but it seems there is no solution to the 'signals getting discarded' problem other than collecting the children wioth some form of wait() and leaving out the handler.

Comment: Your solution works with a slight change. waitpid() returns 0, if WNOHANG is the reason it returns. So editing the while statement should let the code work correctly. It might differ between systems though.